# Multiple click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some popup dialogs on my webpage, in each of these dialogs I have defined some click event with jQuery :

```
 $(".links_view").click(function(e){     //code     });
```

But the problem is when I activate one this click event, it will be executed in each dialog...

Comment: could you please post the function's code?

Comment: Are you using `$(this)` to refer to the clicked element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".links_view").click(function(e){  e.preventDefault()   });
```

also have your dialogs different class OR id!?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to isolate your click attachment; to do this, just make your selector (currently ".links_view") more specific.

For example, if you have the following HTML

```
<div id="one">
  <button class="links_view">Hi</button>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <button class="links_view">Ho</button>
</div>
```

the code `$('.links_view')` will grab both, but you can use `$('#one .links_view')` to just get the first or `$('#two .links_view')` for the second.

Here's a good tutorial on selectors: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref